# When i execute $firebase deploy command i get this error?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

> I want to create an http function to upload image to firebase storage using firebase cloud functions.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.3.0",
    "busboy": "^0.2.14",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  }
```

**Error**

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a7me63azza8/Desktop/flutter/flutter_course/functions/index.js:21:45)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase- 
tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
```

**Error screen shot**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am doing the udemy flutter course as well, and there was a document that asked you to install version 1.7 of @google-cloud/storage.

This worked for me, run:

npm install --save @google-cloud/storage@1.7

then run: firebase deploy

Comment: That cost me an hour of my life I'll never get back, what a bloody disaster. Downgrading to v1.7 fixed the issue, unbelievable. Cheers pal, you saved me night.